# Inconsistent space formatting in revisions history

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, diff, whitespace

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11749795/revisions) page of edit revisions, when you view them in markdown source code, there is some inconsistency: leading spaces apparently always get converted to `&nbsp;` but other spaces *in common lines* don't. In *edited lines,* on the other hand, every space appears to be subject to that replacement. Which makes the alignment between common and modified lines look pretty weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice catch, thanks. The conversion to `&nbsp;` happend to prevent successive spaces to be collapsed into one, because in the Markdown view, they're significant. But of course there's a better way to do this, and it also makes sure it happens *everywhere*: Via the css `white-space` property. So that's what we'll be doing from the next build on.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142031.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @msh210.