# Revision mark-down source diff bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, diff

Is this a bug of Stack Overflow, or this is a browser bug? The text is not wrapped properly.

I'm using Firefox 14.0.1 on Windows 7. The page in the screenshot is the revision page of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11779057/revisions).

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyOMC.png]

I fiddled around with the inspector in Firefox. After I changed the property `white-space` from `pre` to `pre-wrap` for `#revisions .markdown-diff .full-diff td.content`, then the problem disappeared.

Comment: Wraps fine here (SeaMonkey). Browser bug.

Comment: No such issue in Chrome either.

Comment: Wraps fine on FF14.0.1 running on Win 7.

Comment: @H.Muster: Not sure, I even open it on a clean profile. It has the same overflowing text problem.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Funny: I can reproduce this bug when use Private Browsing (i.e. then I am logged out + no cookies). But while logged in, everything looks fine.

Comment: I see it on 14.0.1 on Mac as well.

Comment: FF 14.0.1 Ubuntu, same bug.

Comment: Just saw it here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11470451/revisions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears we've hit an area here where CSS browser compatibility can still use some work. I checked five browsers, and got three different results: Safari and IE agree, Chrome and Opera agree, and Firefox stands all alone, also being the only one where it looks really totally broken.

When using `pre-wrap` as Martijn Pieters [suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142031/115866) (and it's really the better solution), they all agree. Fixed in the next build. Thanks!

Comment: I may just be spoiled by how efficient you usually are, but has the build in question gone out? I'm still seeing the bug at [this suggested edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4064).

Comment: No, it's not yet. I'll build out in a few minutes.

Comment: Should be good now.

Comment: Yep, looks fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I certainly see this on Mac OS X 10.7.4, Firefox 14.0.1 as well.

The use of the `white-space` CSS property is a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141848), and I think it wasn't tested with enough diffs. Using `pre-wrap` instead of `pre` is, to my eyes, the correct fix.