# Revision diff columns overflowing

Tags: bug, markdown, editor, diff

I was editing [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830113/acessing-post-variables-after-an-ajax-form-submit), and I formatted the code better (markdown *hates* code with tab characters in it).  When I was viewing the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11830113/revisions) (in source side-by-side diff mode), some of the lines were really long, and the red highlight overflowed into the left side.

Screenshot for better explaination:

[image: The red highlight is overflowing its box]

It's not that big of an issue, just a visual bug that kinda bugs me (no pun intended).

P.S. This also happens when the left side has lines that are too long (whitespace after the code).

[image: The green highlight is overflowing its box]

Comment: Indeed. At the time I made [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141756/suggested-edits-on-posts-with-100-votes-overflows-the-icon-box) they were not overflowing. So it looks like the devs are still hammering at the code.

Comment: Real devs never stop hammering at the code.

Comment: As of 2 days ago, they were overflowing in the suggested edit pages. I guess that got fixed already. So this seems like a new one.

Comment: Did I [mention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142066/115866) that web browsers and whitespace are a PITA?

Comment: @balpha: No, you did not.  Please enlighten us! :-) `/sarcasm`